# what is equivalent command of unix which in VMS

Tags: unix, openvms, vms

I have a tool **xyz** in vms.I want to get location where it is installed.For example in **unix** we can achieve this by using **which** command.So please help me vms equivalent of this command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent command of which in VMS. To find the location of such a tool it depends on how the tool is set up on VMS. VMS commands can be DCL commands, aka DCL verbs, or foreign commands, aka DCL symbols. I assume you invoke the xyz tool with just typing "xyz" at the DCL command prompt.

DCL verbs are defined in a DCL command table. Your system administrator may have added the xyz tool to one of the DCL command tables, for example with the `$ SET COMMAND` command in the system wide LOGIN command procedure. If your tool is set up as a DCL command, you may want to get and look at the VERB utility (this utility is available from the VMS freeware CD), which will show you your XYZ command, with a DCl command `$ VERB XYZ`. Its output will list an "image" line, so anything after that keyword is the (file) specification of the tool's executable image. The default directory here is `SYS$SYSTEM`, which is a logical name. Keep in mind that the specification can be a (full) VMS file specification or just a logical name.

For foreign commands - almost always used for tools ported from Unix - you can check for the DCL symbol with the DCL command `$ SHOW SYMBOL XYZ`. If the tool is setup up this way, you will see an output like "XYZ == $file_ specification". Again, the file specification can be a (full) VMS file specification or just a logical name.

Additionally, recent versions of VMS support automatic foreign commands. That is, executable images (and command procedures), which are found in the directoy/-ies pointed to by the logical name `DCL$PATH`, will automatically be used as a foreign command. So your tool xyz may be a file in such a directory. This would be the easiest way to find its location: `$ DIRECTORY DCL$PATH:XYZ` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since **user2116290** has mentioned the freeware `VERB` utility I'll put in a plug for another freeware utility called [DFU](http:///www.digiater.nl/dfu.html)  (for Disk/File Utilities).

One thing DFU can do is to search a disk volume's index file for all files matching a particular name. (It can also search by date, file size, file owner, and more).

DFU can do a lot of other useful things. Have a look at the website I linked to above for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A hands-on way to locate the EXE-image. That's what I would do:

0. Ask your colleague or VMS admin
1. Check a **foreign command**, e.g. MYEXE  (`MYEXE :== $SOMEWHERE:[DIR]MYEXE.EXE`):

   ```
   SHOW SYMBOL/GLOBAL MYEXE
   DIR 'f$string(MYEXE - "$")
   ```
2. Check a **foreign batch command**, e.g. MYCOM  (`MYCOM :== @SOMEWHERE:[DIR]MYCOM.COM`):

   ```
   DIR 'f$string(MYCOM - "@")
   ```
3. Check a defined **DCL command verb**, e.g. MYVERB (`SET COM MYCOMMANDS.CLD`) -- this one is the trickiest, depending on how .CLD file was processed), you may need a `VERB` utility (VMS freeware) to extract the details of the command verb from DCLTABLES.EXE

   ```
   HELP MYVERB
   HELP VERB
   DIR SYS$SYSTEM:MYVERB.EXE
   ```

However, if you got to this point in your search, I would actually look through the LOGIN procedures, that's where such verb would potentially be set from a .CLD file ... unless the custom DCLTABLES where directly installed. So it *is* tricky and should be directed to the admin.

```
   SEARCH SYS$LOGIN:LOGIN.COM MYVERB, "SET COM", ".CLD"
   SEARCH SYS$MANAGER:SY*.COM MYVERB, "SET COM", ".CLD"
```

Still, the easiest is to ASK your colleague or your friendly VMS-admin... unless your are both of them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use....

```
$ PRODUCT SHOW HISTORY
```

the above command will help you to show installed products.